# Program not asking for administrator rights, while already using a manifest

Tags: c#, .net, manifest, administrator

My program is not asking for administrator privileges while I do have a manifest file included in my project, I loaded it correctly, it just simply doesnt want to fix the error I have in my code. I'll post the manifest file, but I'm almost sure its fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>-->

</application>
```

</dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->

These are the settings I am using in my project:

[image: Settings]

The error I am getting:

[image: Error]

Translated it says: 
"Win32 Exception was unhandled, Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller."

Can I have any help, so I can make my program ask for administrator privileges so it can run correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify `<requestedExecutionLevel>`

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

See here: [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)